# unable to clone git repo on new machine

Tags: git, authentication

I am a new programming student and was previously using gitbash to upload my projects to gitlab. My laptop recently broke and I am using a new one, however I am having trouble connecting to my previous gitlab account on my new laptop. I have been looking on google and stackoverflow for information on logging into gitbash using a previously created gitlab account but can only find information on logging into git creating a new account with new SSH keys.

Everytime i try to log in using the following commands:

git config --global user.name "Jane Smith"
git config --global user.email jsmith@fitchburg.edu

It will not allow me to clone from my fork on gitlab, stating "could not read from remote repository, please make sure you have the correct access rights. Please help me figure out how to log in on my new laptop so I can continue my projects.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a new SSH key on that laptop and ad that to your gitlab account. [Here is how](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-your-ssh-keys.html).